# How do a make a query to count which string appears the most in a certain column?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm making a program and I need to make a query to the database asking for the string that appears most often in a given column. In this example, its "stringONE".

```
----------------------------
|  ID  |  Column (string)  |
----------------------------
|  1   |     stringONE     |
----------------------------
|  2   |     stringTWO     |
----------------------------
|  3   |     stringONE     |
----------------------------
|  4   |     stringONE     |
----------------------------
```

Now I need to take the name of the string that appears the most and put it into a variable string, for example:

```
string most_appeared_string = sql.ExecuteScalar();
```

Also, what happens if there is no string that appears the most, rather 2 or more strings that appear the same amount of times, like this:

```
----------------------------
|  ID  |  Column (string)  |
----------------------------
|  1   |     stringONE     |
----------------------------
|  2   |     stringTWO     |
----------------------------
|  3   |     stringTWO     |
----------------------------
|  4   |     stringONE     |
----------------------------
```

Thanks ahead.

---

@KeithS

Do you have an sql-server version of the query because I'm getting some errors when trying it there. Here's a table example of what I'd like to do precisely.

```
------------------------------------------------
|  ID  |  column1 (string) |  author (string)  |
------------------------------------------------
|  1   |     string-ONE    |       John        |
------------------------------------------------
|  2   |     string-TWO    |       John        |
------------------------------------------------
|  3   |     string-ONE    |      Martin       |
------------------------------------------------
|  4   |     string-ONE    |       John        |
------------------------------------------------

SELECT TOP (1) column1, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE author='John' ORDER BY ID
```

It should return "string-ONE" since it appears the most (2) times for the author John. When trying the query in MS-SQL Management Studio though, this is the error I'm getting:

```
Column 'table.column1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

---

Nevermind the edit. Thank you.

Comment: It could be. I'm a noob, studying databases this semester and I'm doing some personal programming projects at home in order to learn more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty easy query (in T-SQL at least):

```
select top 1 Column, Count(*) from Table group by Column order by Count(*) desc
```

ExecuteScalar, by an implementation detail, will return the string value because it's the first column of the only row in the result set, even though there are two columns. You could also use ExecuteReader to access the number of times that string occurs.

Answer (score 2):

```
select top (1) SomeCol, count(*) as Row_Count
from YourTable
group by SomeCol
order by Row_Count desc
```

> Also, what happens if there is no string that appears the most, rather
>   2 or more strings that appear the same amount of times, like this:

In that case,  using the above query, you will get **one** arbitrary row. You can add `with ties` to get all rows that has the same highest value.

```
select top (1) with ties SomeCol, count(*) as Row_Count
from YourTable
group by SomeCol
order by Row_Count desc
```

Comment: Can you explain how I can take these multiple values and put them into different textBoxes in C#?

Comment: @user1200185 No not really. I don't do C#. I guess you have some kind of query object that executes the query and returns a dataset with multiple rows. You have to loop over the rows in C# and assign your variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT max(counted) AS max_counted FROM (
   SELECT count(*) AS counted FROM counter GROUP BY date
 )
```

This could do the trick

Comment: You're never returning the actual string value that occurs most in a column.